# ¿"Degeneración" significa diferentes casos indistinguibles entre sí solo en contextos de física y de matemáticas para físicos?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, vocabulario-técnico, matemáticas, ciencia

La pregunta que voy a hacer es sobre vocabulario técnico (y no sé si va a ser fácil de contestar).

En el contexto de unos trabajos realizados por unos alumnos de bachillerato, estaba hablando de un problema de matemáticas con una persona. Se trataba de lo que a mí me gusta llamar *problema de contar*, pero quizás alguien lo entienda mejor si lo denomino *problema de combinatoria*.

En un cierto momento de la conversación, mi interlocutor dijo esta frase:

> Hay que dividir entre la *degeneración*.

En ese momento pensé: ¡Qué bonito! ¡Cuánto tiempo hace que no oía esta palabra: "degeneración"!

Pero luego me puse a darle vueltas al tema. Ocurre que la persona con la que hablé es un físico (pero, que quede claro: no hablamos de física: el contexto del problema era el [juego del "set"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(card_game))). Empecé a tener mis dudas sobre si una persona que no fuera un físico hubiera entendido el significado de "degeneración" en esa frase.

Como física, yo digo que hay "degeneración" cuando pasa que diferentes casos de algo son indistinguibles entre sí desde algún punto de vista que se está estudiando. La "degeneración" sería el número de casos indistinguibles entre sí.

Pongo un ejemplo sencillo para que se entienda el tipo de cosas de las que estábamos hablando. Supongamos que de una baraja de 40 cartas sacamos 3 cartas. Queremos calcular de cuántas maneras diferentes lo podemos hacer, es decir, queremos ver cuántos grupos diferentes de 3 cartas podemos hacer.

Podemos recurrir a fórmulas de números combinatorios, pero si lo queremos razonar de forma sencilla lo podemos hacer de la manera siguiente:

- Para la primera carta tenemos 40 diferentes.
- Una vez fijada la primera carta, cada una de ellas se puede combinar con cada una de las 39 cartas restantes y cada una de estas 39 cartas lo puede hacer con las 38 restantes: podéis imaginar un diagrama de árbol.
- Para contar las "ramas del árbol" tenemos que hacer la multiplicación 40 · 39 · 38.

Pero tenemos "degeneración" porque el grupo de 3 cartas ABC es, por ejemplo, el mismo que BAC: todas las permutaciones de ABC son el mismo grupo de cartas (las permutaciones de ABC son todas las posibles maneras de ordenar las 3 letras A, B y C). Para calcular cuántos grupos diferentes de 3 cartas podemos sacar de la baraja tenemos que dividir el resultado de la multiplicación anterior entre la "degeneración", que es 3! = 3 · 2 · 1 = 6.<sup>1</sup>  De todas formas, creo que esto es un uso impropio del término "degeneración" (comprensibile entre físicos, pero que probablemente no se encuentre escrito en ningún libro ni artículo).

Lo único que se me ha ocurrido hacer es buscar en el [*Diccionari de matemàtiques i estadística*](https://books.google.es/books/about/Diccionari_de_matem%C3%A0tiques_i_estad%C3%ADsti.html?id=LQ5yPQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) que tengo en casa: está en catalán, pero en catalán yo diría "degeneració" con exactamente el mismo significado. Además, este diccionario proporciona las traducciones al castellano, al inglés y al francés de todos los términos y permite buscar las palabras en castellano, en inglés y en francés a través de unos índices que contienen todos los vocablos en esas lenguas ordenados alfabéticamente.

Efectivamente, no se encuentra "degeneración" ni "degeneració" con el significado que he descrito. Únicamente aparece el adjetivo "degenerado -ada" (en catalán sería "degenerat -ada") con una acepción completamente diferente, que, traduciendo al castellano, sería esta:

> Dicho del caso límite de algún tipo de objeto que es equivalente a un tipo más simple, frecuentemente haciendo que algún coeficiente o parámetro sea cero. Un punto es el caso degenerado de una circunferencia de radio cero.

Leer esto hizo aumentar mis sospechas de que "degeneración" con el significado que he descrito antes quizás es algo sólo de físicos, pero podría ser que en algún otro campo se usase esta palabra con este sentido.

Después, pensando mejor sobre el tema, me di cuenta de que "degeneración" con este sentido se usa en matemáticas seguro, porque el concepto de "degeneración" que se utiliza en mecánica cuántica viene en realidad de una definición de "degeneración" del ámbito de las matemáticas. Me refiero a cuando se buscan los valores propios y los vectores propios de un endomorfismo de un espacio vectorial. Se dice que hay "degeneración" cuando a un valor propio le corresponde un número mayor que uno de vectores propios linealmente independientes. Al valor propio al que le pasa esto se le llamaría "valor propio degenerado". Y la "degeneración" sería la dimensión del subespacio vectorial (el "eigenspace") correspondiente a ese valor propio (el conjunto de todos los vectores propios correspondientes a ese valor propio). Pero, aparte de este contexto matemático, no sé si hay otros contextos fuera del ámbito de la física en que se use "degeneración" con el sentido que he explicado (aunque los físicos lo hagamos, pero probablemente impropiamente). Y además  tengo la sospecha de que la nomenclatura que he mencionado sea algo exclusivo de físicos. Sé que a lo que he llamado "degeneración" se le puede llamar "multiplicidad del valor propio" (de manera más exacta sería la "multiplicidad geométrica del valor propio"). Preguntando a unas amigas matemáticas, esta es la única nomenclatura que han visto usar. Posiblemente "degeneración" en este contexto matemático sólo lo usen los físicos.

¿Alguien lo sabría aclarar?

---

<sup>1. Y si no queremos utilizar el factorial 3! para calcular cuántas permutaciones hay, también lo podemos hacer imaginándonos un sencillo diagrama de árbol. Empezamos poniendo las 3 letras: A, B, C. Cada una de estas 3 letras la combinamos con una segunda letra *diferente* para obtener una pareja de letras: cada una de las 3 letras se puede aparejar con 2 letras. Y ahora, para obtener las permutaciones, a cada pareja se le puede añadir una y sólo una letra (porque tiene que ser diferente de las otras dos). Por lo tanto, tenemos 3 · 2 · 1 = 6 permutaciones.</sup>

Comment: Yo había oído muchas veces la palabra con el sentido matemático que has encontrado en tu diccionario, pero nunca con el físico. Esto no significa que no se use, claro; solo es mi caso personal. Y yo soy ingeniero, así que estudié ciencias en la universidad, aunque no sea científco.

Comment: @Gorpik: De hecho, tanto en física como en matemáticas (al fin y al cabo la física consiste en modelos matemáticos), la palabra "degenerado" puede tener otros significados a parte de los dos que se explican en la pregunta. Por ejemplo, los modelos de la relatividad general parten siempre de variedades riemannianas: son variedades que tienen definida una métrica, que se define como un campo de tensores covariantes de orden 2 simétrico y no degenerado. Aquí la definición de "degenerado" (o de "no degenerado") sería [esta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_bilinear_form).

Comment: @fedorqui: Me parece un poco raro una coma y un interrogante que separen sujeto y verbo. El resto de la modificación del título de la pregunta me parece bien.

Comment: [El DPD lo da por bueno](https://www.rae.es/dpd/interrogación): _Los vocativos y las construcciones u oraciones dependientes, cuando ocupan el primer lugar del enunciado, se escriben fuera de la pregunta o de la exclamación_, pero es tu pregunta así que ponla como mejor refleje tu escritura :) Por cierto, ¿la _Física_ del enunciado no iría en mayúscula?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming': No tengo claro que se trate de un vocativo. Tampoco tengo nada claro que "física" se tenga que escribir con la primera letra en mayúscula.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming': La [*Ortografía de la lengua española*](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UGxdQRValgAQHkQp) de la RAE dice que va con minúscola.

Comment: Yo me basé en [mayúsculas del DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/mayúsculas) cuando dice _Los sustantivos y adjetivos que forman el nombre de disciplinas científicas, cuando nos referimos a ellas como materias de estudio, y especialmente en contextos académicos (nombres de asignaturas, cátedras, facultades, etc.) o curriculares_. El enlace que tú das es la versión más reciente y veo que más restrictiva, si bien deja algo de margen a la interpretación.

Comment: En mi opinión, @Charo tiene razón en que *física* va aquí en minúsculas; no hablamos de la cátedra de Física Teórica, ni de la facultad de Física, ni de la asignatura de Física del Estado Sólido. La disciplina en sí no lleva mayúscula si no es en los contextos que especifica el DPD.

Comment: Y, también en mi opinión, la lleva @fedorqui'SOstopharming' en el asunto de la coma :) No es un vocativo, pero sí una construcción dependiente.

Comment: @Gorpik: Yo lo veo simplemente como el sujeto de la frase, pero quizás sí que se pueda escribir fuera de la pregunta, no sé.

Comment: Se me ha ocurrido preguntar por ahí (a pocas personas, en condiciones de normalidad supongo que lo podría haber hecho a más). A parte de lo mencionado en la pregunta, un amigo me ha dicho que ha encontrado en [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(mathematics)) que las raíces de un polinomio se llaman "degeneradas" cuando son iguales: "Roots of a polynomial are said to be degenerate if they coincide, since generically the *n* roots of an *n*th degree polynomial are all distinct". (sigue)

Comment: (cont.) No me suena haber visto usar "degeneración" en este contexto: creo que yo siempre he usado "multiplicidad". Pero se trata de un ejemplo que correspondería a lo que pido. La pregunta es: ¿hay más ejemplos?

Answer (score 2):

El significado más común de **[degeneración](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneraci%C3%B3n_(matem%C3%A1ticas))** en matemáticas es el que viene en el diccionario que citas: un caso límite de un objeto matemático que lo transforma en otro más simple.

En cuanto al significado por el que preguntas (multiplicidad de casos), mi experiencia es la siguiente.

### Álgebra lineal

La dimensión del autoespacio vectorial (=espacio vectorial propio) asociado a un autovalor (=valor propio) se denomina **multiplicidad geométrica** del autovalor. Este es el único nombre que aparece [en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_propio_y_valor_propio#Introducci%C3%B3n), y el que yo he usado siempre. [Otras fuentes](http://webdelprofesor.ula.ve/ciencias/nunez/cursos/MetodosMatematicos2/2006A/Met1ClsEspVect6A05.pdf) (Sección 3.2; nótese que se trata de un texto universitario de una facultad de Física) llaman *autovalores degenerados* a los autovalores cuyo autoespacio asociado tiene dimensión mayor que 1, y llaman **orden de degeneración** a esta dimensión. Sin embargo, no he encontrado ninguna fuente que utilice la palabra *degeneración* para denotar al número (la dimensión) en sí. Aún más interesante, la gran mayoría de resultados de la búsqueda en Google de "[degeneración de un autovalor](https://www.google.com/search?q=degeneraci%C3%B3n%20de%20un%20autovalor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)" están relacionados con la física cuántica.

### Combinatoria

No encuentro ninguna fuente que denomine *degeneración* al número de permutaciones que aparece en el denominador de la fórmula para calcular [combinaciones sin repetición](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatoria#Combinaciones_sin_repetici%C3%B3n). El artículo de Wikipedia no incluye la palabra *degeneración*. En mis estudios, nunca se le ha dado un nombre distinto a *permutaciones*.

### Mecánica cuántica

En este caso no puedo basarme en mi propia experiencia, sino en lo que encuentro en Internet. **[Degeneración](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneraci%C3%B3n_(f%C3%ADsica))** es

> [e]l hecho de que un mismo nivel de energía (autovalor del operador hamiltoniano) posea más de un estado asociado (autofunción del operador hamiltoniano con el mismo autovalor).

No solo esto, sino que **degeneración** también denota al número de estados asociados:

> El número g_n se denomina degeneración del n-ésimo nivel energético.

### Resumen

El término **degeneración** con el significado de "multiplicidad" parece estar mucho más extendido en el campo de la mecánica cuántica que en otros campos de las matemáticas o la física. Especialmente el uso del término **degeneración** para denotar al número de casos (y no solo al hecho de que hay multiplicidad de casos).

Comment: En realidad la definición que se usa en mecánica cuántica es exactamente la misma que la de álgebra lineal que mencionas y el caso que has puesto en la respuesta sería solo un ejemplo. Un operador (como el Hamiltoniano) en mecánica cuántica es un endomorfismo de un espacio vectorial (un espacio de Hilbert en concreto) y los estados de que hablas, que se suelen llamar "estados propios", son en realidad vectores propios linealmente independientes.

Comment: Puede que yo (y otros físicos, te lo aseguro) llame "degeneración" a lo que tu llamas "orden de degeneración" por algún proceso de simplificación del lenguaje. Luego busco haber si lo encuentro en algún libro por casa en castellano.

Comment: El único libro en castellano que he conseguido encontrar por casa que habla de esto, no utiliza "degeneración", ni "grado de degeneración", sino "multiplicidad del valor propio". Bueno, que parece que hay diferentes nomenclaturas.

Comment: @Charo sí, parece que es un término que se usa sobre todo en física con ese significado (y por eso yo no lo había oído nunca).

Comment: Cada vez estoy más convencida de que se usa solo en física. Hace un par de días, por pura casualidad, me encontré con una definición correspondiente a esta idea en un diccionario italiano, pero que sorprendentemente aparece con la marca "*mat*.". Me da la sensación que es un error y que debería decir "*fis.*". Esto me llevó a hacer esta [pregunta en Italian.SE](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13004/), que no parece haber tenido mucho éxito (pero también es que últimamente me da la sensación que Italian.SE está casi desierto).

Comment: Es un buen diccionario, que tiene prestigio: puedes ver en los comentarios que hay quien paga por tener la última versión. En todo caso hay un comentario de un matemático que dice lo mismo: no lo había oído nunca.

Comment: @Charo es una pregunta difícil, es normal que no tenga respuestas en un día. A fin de cuentas, esta pregunta aquí en Spanish.SE ha tardado dos meses en tener una respuesta qur ni siquiera es una respuesta completa...

Comment: Sí, tienes razón que es una pregunta difícil (aunque hay que decir que Italian.SE tiene la suerte de tener como usuarios a unos cuantos matemáticos). Pero mi sensación por como funcionan las cosas últimamente (ojalá me equivoque) es que acabará cayendo en el olvido.

Comment: @Charo ahora que vuelve a tener 0 votos, tardará un año en desaparecer... esperemos que pase algo (positivo) en ese tiempo.